# Abstract identical column name from different dataframes to merge a new different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
time  A  B  C  ... N           time   A     B    C  ...  N
 1/1  a  c                     1/1    aa    cc
 1/2  b  d                     1/2    bb    dd                   ....
 ...                           ...
        W1                                W2
```

There are several DataFrames(W1,W2,...) as shown above which represents different properties of A to N. How to merge identical columns names from these DataFrames so that different properties of one column can be shown in one DataFrame?

Expected output:

```
time  W1  W2 ...                        time   W1   W2   ...
1/1   a   aa                             1/1   c    cc
1/2   b   bb                             1/2   d    dd               ...
...                                      ...
        A                                          B
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

If I understood correctly you need to perform :

```
import pandas as pd
new_df = pd.concat([W1, W2, W3])
```

Comment: Not exactly. I want to abstract A column from different dataframe to merge a new dataframe which will have the same row size with the previous dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
# there are 2 dfs by df1 and df2 and both have column A
df1A = df.loc[df['A']]
df2A = df.loc[df['A']]
final_df = pd.concat([df1A,df2A], sort=True)
```

Comment: **concat** does not exist keyword argument 'sort'. And I have already tried this kind of method: abstracting two and merging. But the question is there are so many dataframe to be abstracted, I want a simpler method.

Comment: As per pandas docs 0.23.4 concat does have the keyword argument sort. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html

Comment: Do you ave all the df strored in a list or in some sort of DS.